# How to assign objects to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So my array currently assign 5 instances of a dice object. My issue is that I have another class that needs to lock a dice from use.

```
   public class Yahtzee {
        OneDice[] dice = new OneDice[5];

        public Yahtzee() {
            yahtzeeRoll(); //constructor
        }

        public void yahtzeeRoll() {
            for (int i = 0; i != dice.length; i++) {
                dice[i] = new OneDice();
            }
  public void lock(int which) {

        dice[which - 1].lockDice();
        }
  }
```

however my dice[i] = new OneDice(); creates a whole new set of random numbers each time yahtzeeRoll is called.

here is the method passing the which parameter.

```
   @Override
    public void choose() {
        int which;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(getName() + " Rolling.");
        hand.printYahtzee();

        System.out.println("Would you like to lock dice 1? 1 for yes");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            which = 1;
            hand.lock(which);
        }
```

how can I assign a random value to each dice index without creating a brand new set of rolls that negates the lock. At least that appears to be the issue to me?

Comment: Why at all are you calling that method from constructor, instead of doing the initialization part in the constructor itself?

Comment: Rolling dice and creating dice are very different things.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to just skip over entries which *are* locked:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
    if (dice[i] == null || !dice[i].isLocked()) {
        dice[i] = new OneDice();
    }
}
```

Either that, or change your code to initialize `dice` in the constructor with new instances, but make your `yahtzeeRoll` method just change the values *within* the existing unlocked instances, instead of creating new instances. For example:

```
public Yahtzee() {
    for (int i = 0; i  < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = new OneDice();
    }
    rollUnlocked();
}

public void rollUnlocked() { // Renamed from yahtzeeRoll for clarity
    for (OneDice die : dice) {
        die.rollIfUnlocked(); // Or whatever method you want
    }
}
```

(where `rollIfUnlocked` would reroll the single die, only if it hadn't previously been locked).

Comment: Yes I was thinking I could put something in that would skip over any dice that were locked but was uncertain how to accomplish this but he later suggestion seems perhaps a better solution. Thanks as I am very new to java and struggling a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinitialize the entire array each time you roll.  In real life when playing yahtzee you don't go grab 5 new dice every time you roll.

Answer (score 0):

create OneDice as follows:

```
class OneDice {
   int value;
   boolean locked;

   void roll(){
      if(!locked)
         value = Math.nextInt(6);
   }

   int getValue(){
      return value;
   }
   void setLock(boolean lock){
      locked = lock;
   }
   boolean isLocked(){
      return locked;
   }
}
```